# CoreData get data for base class using predicate on drived class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

**In short >> list of all countries with their favorite websites only.**

[image: Problem diagram]

I want list of all Countries having the "isFav = YES" in Websites. Can I do that using a predicate query please help?

Comment: Maybe like so? : 

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL websites.isFav == YES"];

Comment: this one is not working either

Comment: You really should have a bi-directional relationship here. Core Data warns about it and that warning should not be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @James Richard is correct.  However you need to take it a step further than just the predicate.

The predicate will return you the country objects.  Then you need to add a convenience method (or just write the filter every time you want the answer) that filters the websites.

For example, in your `Country` entity subclass you could have this method:

```
- (NSSet*)favoriteWebsites
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFav == YES"];
    NSSet *websites = [self valueForKey:@"websites"];
    NSSet *favorites = [websites filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return favorites;
}
```

BTW, you should always have bi-directional relationships in core data.  The risk of corrupting your data is **great**.  Likewise, Core Data naming convention is to not prepend the word `is` to attributes.  The attribute should be just `favorite` and then the getter accessor can be configured with `isFavorite`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

The predicate you would have to do is:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY websites.isFav == YES"]
```

This document might help with other predicate formatting:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW3

Comment: Not working for me, It returns the country object, and object contains all websites (isFav and isNotFav). I want only favorite website.

Comment: Right. You can't restrict Core Data to have only one object in their relationship set. This will grab any Country object that has a favorite website. If you want to filter out all other Websites from that list of countries you'll have to do it as a method within the Country object, OR fetch the Websites that are marked as favorite and then ask for the country object (looks like you don't have a bidirectional relationship, but you should have a relationship to Country from Websites.)